# Trying to display the Title on the page under the categories

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-float

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <style type="text/css">

    body {background-color: #D3D3D3;}
    table {
    width: 30%;

     border-collapse: collapse;

}

td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
p.one {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
}
p.groove {border-style: groove;

  height: 400px;
    width: 400px;

}

    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
$scope.categoryL = '';
  $scope.categoryList = function(value) {
    $scope.categoryL = value;
  }
  $scope.selectedCategory = {};
  $scope.menus = [{
    "Forms": [{
      "title": "Book a Meeting Room",
      "category": "Forms",
      "url": "https://www.google.co.uk/",
    },
    {
    "title": "Book a Pool Car",
    "category": "Forms",
    "url": "https://www.google.co.uk/"
    },
    {
    "title": "Order Stationery",
    "category": "Forms",
    "url": "https://www.google.co.uk/"
    },
    {
    "title": "Gift & Hospitality",
    "category": "Forms",
    "url": "https://www.google.co.uk/"
    }]
  }, {
    "News": [{
      "title": "Discovery Communications embraces Office 365",
    "category": "News",
    "url": "https://blogs.office.com/2016/07/18/discovery-communications-embraces-office-365-to-foster-creative-culture-of-innovation/"
  },
  {
    "title": "Guardian Industries",
    "category": "News",
    "url": "https://blogs.office.com/2016/07/15/guardian-industries-connect-collaborate-and-innovate-from-anywhere/"
  },
  {
    "title": "Data Loss Prevention Policy Tips in OneDrive",
    "category": "News",
    "url": "https://blogs.office.com/2016/07/14/data-loss-prevention-policy-tips-in-onedrive-mobile-apps/"
  }]
  },
{
    "Useful Information": [{
    "title": "Get started with SharePoint",
    "category": "Useful Information",
    "url": "https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-started-with-SharePoint-909ec2f0-05c8-4e92-8ad3-3f8b0b6cf261"
  },
  {
    "title": "What is SharePoint?",
    "category": "Useful Information",
    "url": "https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-is-SharePoint-97b915e6-651b-43b2-827d-fb25777f446f"
  },
  {
    "title": "Accessibility features in SharePoint Online",
    "category": "Useful Information",
    "url": "https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Accessibility-features-in-SharePoint-Online-f291404a-dc7e-44de-a31f-d81b3099c2b9?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US"
  },
  {
    "title": "Videos for SharePoint Online and SharePoint 2013",
    "category": "Useful Information",
    "url": "https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Videos-for-SharePoint-Online-and-SharePoint-2013-ed074945-4ddc-4479-9efe-6b3945cf8266?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US"
  }]
  }]

 $scope.labels = [];

  (function getMenuLabels() {
    angular.forEach($scope.menus, function(menu) {
      $scope.labels.push({
        label: Object.keys(menu)[0],
        moreInformation: menu[Object.keys(menu)[0]]
        });
    })
      $scope.selectedCategory = $scope.labels[0];
  })();
});

    </script>
  </head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<div class="center">
  <center>
  <p class="groove">
<select width="300" style="width:400px" ng-model="selectedCategory" ng-options="label.label for label in labels"></select>
  <section class="categoryL">
    <b ng-repeat="info in selectedCategory.moreInformation">
        <br>
          <table align="center" class="ex2" style="border:1px solid yellowgreen;">
            <tr>
              <td BGCOLOR="#ff00ff"><a ng-href="{{info.url}}">{{info.title}}</a></td>
            </tr/>
          </table>
  </section>
</center>
</div>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi, if you load my code into a file you will see that i have added some CSS, however i am finding it difficult to add the links inside the border that i have created, i have managed to get the drop down inside the border but for some reason i can not add the links.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question, but you can display title with another ng-repeat (I edited your first section) https://plnkr.co/edit/8ItCgNT4xPbpLnKbYawf?p=preview:

```
<section class="choices">
<div class="categories">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="menu in menus">
      <div ng-repeat="(key,val) in menu">
        <a href="" ng-click="categoryList(key)">{{key}}</a>
        <div ng-repeat="titles in val">{{titles.title}}</div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you - you are on the right track however i want the information that you have put under the titles to be under the List also i want the information to disappears when the category is clicks on. if that makes sense. so its like showing all the information before the category is clicked on and only show the specific information for that category. that is where the issue is for me. thank you for looking into this

Comment: omg thank you, this is looking so much better. however can i be a pain one more time and ask for a small tweak....could i get all of the URL presented when the page is loaded and when each category is selected it will only show them links for that category

Comment: Sorry, i can't answer now but tomorrow. Can you clarify your question. I'm not sure I understand

Comment: Don't be sorry, you have helped alot! The last thing i can not do for some reason, is that i can not put the categories in the drop down menu, so i want the form,news and useful information inside a drop down menu and then present the information. for some reason i am having an issue with this!

Comment: I update my plunker, I suggest to you in controller to manage your data structure to extract label menu. And after you can display a drop down.

Comment: Thank you for that! i was spending so much time trying to put it in a drop down menu. Also when i load the page within the drop down is empty, how can i load Forms instead of it being empty in the drop down.

Comment: Just put in selectedCategory the category you want in getMenuLabels methods --> $scope.selectedCategory = $scope.labels[0]; (plunker updated)

Comment: Hi, i appreciate the help so much, but when i load your plunker it still does not load with forms within the drop down menu still. it is still blank...am i missing something? this is the only bit that i am stuck on, other than that there is nothing left. thank you so much

Comment: HI, that has worked, thank you so much for your help! how can i rate or leave a positive feedback on your profile? also i have updated my code in my original post. i am have difficult with my CSS. could you take a look please?

Comment: Sorry I can't help you with CSS, I'm very bad in design... 
If the question is answered for you just mark it has resolved